# MySQL: User with grant option can't grant create user

Tags: mysql, permissions, privileges, sql-grant

I created a user (new_user) with root like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON labor.* TO 'new_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL ON labor.* TO 'new_user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'new_user'@'%';
GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'new_user'@'localhost';
GRANT RELOAD ON *.* TO 'new_user'@'localhost';
GRANT RELOAD ON *.* TO 'new_user'@'%'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I try to create another user the same way but with new_user, I get an access denied error.
This error occurs after the GRANT ALL lines.

What else privilege should I add?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The newly create user is missing the grant option on `*.*` (needed for `grant create user on *.* ...`)

```
GRANT GRANT OPTION ON *.* TO 'new_user'@'%';
GRANT GRANT OPTION ON *.* TO 'new_user'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to [Xevelion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18593078/10907864)

I had this issue when I created trying to grant a user access to a database

> ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT

**Here's how I fixed it**:

This error occurs when you create the user specifying a particular host and try to grant the same user access specifying a different host.

So in my case, I created a user specifying the database host `aurora-mysql-instance-0.cgi7whhgca9z.eu-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`:

```
CREATE USER 'my_user'@'aurora-mysql-instance-0.cgi7whhgca9z.eu-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'ghy7yyDteh';
```

And then I tried to grant the user access to a database specifying a different host `%`:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_db;
USE my_db;
GRANT ALL ON my_db.* TO 'my_user'@'%';
```

All I had to do was to delete the existing `my_user` user and then recreate it using the host I was to grant it access to:

```
CREATE USER 'my_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'ghy7yyDteh';
```

And then I granted the user access to a database specifying the `%` host:

```
USE my_db;
GRANT ALL ON my_db.* TO 'my_user'@'%';
```

This time everything worked fine.